# Lower bound on a particular infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, power-series, upper-lower-bounds

Consider the following sum:
$$\huge\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ A^{-k} B^{-\frac{\phi^k-1}{\phi-1}} }$$
where $\phi>1$, $A>0$ and $B>1$. The $B$ term dominates the $A$ term for large $k$, so the sum is always finite.

I am looking for a reasonably tight, reasonably simple lower bound on this sum, in terms of $A, B, \phi$.

Obviously one way of obtaining a lower bound is just to truncate the sum, but for small caps, this is unlikely to be tight, and for large caps, it's unlikely to be simple.

[I have given this the power series tag, since this is a power series in $A^{-1}$.]

Comment: The \huge is there because otherwise the power within the power is unreadable.

Comment: You have $(\phi^k-1)/(\phi-1)<k \phi^{k-1}.$ Not sure if that helps much.

Comment: That is why we tend to not use `\frac` in exponents. $$B^{(\phi^k-1)/(\phi-1)}$$ is generally better. Or $$B^{-(1+\phi+\cdots+\phi^{k-1}}$$ Also, you can remove the pesky minus signs in the exponents by letting $C=1/A, D=1/B.$